# How to get the items not found in a Mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a random input of identifiers (primary key), and I need to return the identifiers which were not found in the mySql table.

Lets say my identifier list is `['FEB221571','1221SC170','75960620447200111', 'ABC12344']`.

My table has the first three identifiers so I can find them on the table but I wish the last one to be returned as it cannot be found in the table. How do I implement that?

Answer (score -1):

```sql
select * from identifier_list a
where not exists (select 'x' from some_table b and a.id = b.id);
```